# Creating Automatic price chart for word ranges in php

Tags: php

i want to create an automatic price chart in php. As in the below screenshot i will enter the prices for the number of word ranges and click on save which should create a price chart in a way where i will type the number of words and it will give me calculated price. For example 50 words in 50 USD and 500 words in 150 USD, then it should show calculated price in a way if i write 51 words then the price shouldn't be less than 50 USD.

below is my code which isn't working 100% correct but i need some assistance in it.

```
                if($words >= 1 AND $words <= 5){
                    $given_price = $price_1;
                    $given_words = $words_1;
                    $per_word = $given_price / $given_words;
                }
                if($words > 5 AND $words <= 50){
                    $given_price = $price_2;
                    $given_words = $words_2;
                    $per_word = $given_price / $given_words;
                }
                elseif($words > 50 AND $words <= 500){
                    $given_price = $price_3;
                    $given_words = $words_3;
                    $per_word = $given_price / $given_words;
                }
                elseif($words > 500 AND $words <= 5000){
                    $given_price = $price_4;
                    $given_words = $words_4;
                    $per_word = $given_price / $given_words;
                }
                elseif($words > 5000 AND $words <= 50000){
                    $given_price = $price_5;
                    $given_words = $words_5;
                    $per_word = $given_price / $given_words;
                }
                elseif($words > 50000){
                    $given_price = $price_5;
                    $given_words = $words_5;
                    $per_word = $given_price / $given_words;
                }
                $total_price = $words * $per_word;


$per_word and $per_price are the values of the boxes in below image
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should put the prices into an array or something so we can reduce the boilerplate, and the number of prices can also be changed easily if needed.

```
$prices = array(
    5 => 5,
    50 => 50,
    500 => 150,
    5000 => 4500,
    50000 => 5500
);
$keys = array_keys($prices);

# Find index of the smallest element that has more words than $words.
# After this $words is in range [ prices[i-1], prices[i] )
for ($i = 0; $i < count($prices); ++$i) {
    $given_words = $keys[$i];
    if ($words < $given_words)
        break;
}

$given_price = $prices[$given_words];
if ($i == 0 || $i == count($prices)) {
    $prev_given_words = 0;
    $prev_given_price = 0;
} else {
    $prev_given_words = $keys[$i - 1];
    $prev_given_price = $prices[$prev_given_words];
}

$per_word = ($given_price - $prev_given_price) / ($given_words - $prev_given_words);
$total_price = $prev_given_price + ($words - $prev_given_words) * $per_word;
```

Let me try to explain how it works through an example. Let's calculate the price of 200 words.

200 is between 50 and 500. Here is how the total price changes in terms of the number of words:

[image]

The unit price starting from 50 words is the slope of the line between 50 and 500 words:

```
$per_word = ($150 - $50) / (500 - 50)
```

So the first 50 words cost $50, and the next `200 - 50 = 150` words cost `$per_word` each. Then the total price for 200 is `$50 + (200 - 50) * $per_word`.

Comment: actually the thing is, every user will give their own prices for the word ranges. User A will give $10 for 50 words. user B will give $50 for 50 words. User A will give $150 for 500 word range and user B will give $200 for 500 word range.

Comment: that's not correct as well. i want it this way for example if 50 words are on $50 and 500 words are on $150. if i type 51 words then the price would be slightly increase from $50 maybe in cents and the price should be in price range within $150 if i want the words upto 500.

Comment: for example i write 225 words then the price should be $88.87, if i need 300 words then the price should be something like $101.01 and if i need 400 words then the price should be $127.10 and for 500 words the price should be $150. this is just an example but that should work this way

Comment: that's the best solution. thank you for your help. i ma still trying to understand this logic but didn't understand completely but the result is perfect. thanks alot again.

Comment: is it possible if you can tell me the logic how you did that? i will really appreciate it.

Comment: @NaveedAli I managed to simplify the code and added some explanation.

Comment: thanks alot. i understood now. can you write me on my mail naveedali9480@gmail.com if i will have any project then we will discuss it together, if possible. thank you